# What does the :variable mean?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am relatively new to sqlite using C++, I found a statement like

```
"INSERT INTO files "
    "(md5path_1, md5path_2, parent)"
    "VALUES (:md5_1, :md5_2, :p)"
```

Why are those colons used?

Answer (score 2):

These are called [Bind Variables](https://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html)

With the use of bind variables the statement remains the same, therefore there is only one statement cached as opposed to many.

Answer (score 1):

This is taken from the [introduction to SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html)

> SQLite allows a parameter wherever a string literal, numeric constant,
> or NULL is allowed.  (Parameters may not be used for column or table
> names.)  A parameter takes one of the following forms:
>
> 1. ?
> 2. ?NNN
> 3. ***:AAA***
> 4. $AAA
> 5. @AAA
>
> In the examples above, NNN is an integer value
> and AAA is an identifier. A parameter initially has a value of NULL.
> Prior to calling sqlite3_step() for the first time or immediately
> after sqlite3_reset(), the application can invoke the sqlite3_bind()
> interfaces to attach values to the parameters. Each call to
> sqlite3_bind() overrides prior bindings on the same parameter.

So, it's a placeholder you can bind later to a variable using `sqlite3_bind()`

Answer (score 1):

They called "bind variables". Later in the code you'll definitely see something like

```
exec_query("INSERT....", val1, val2, val3)
```

where val1 - val3 will contain value to be inserted.

Using variables has many advantages. In case of insert statement:

1. It helps to avoid SQL-injections. Thus no one will be able to ruin your query by passing special statements to variables.
2. You don't have to compose sql-statement every time you need it. You can just use that one from your question passing new parameters each time you run it